# Change DOM in all clients when receiving a request/notification

Tags: javascript, dom, push-notification, request

I'm not looking for a solution but more for an approach and technologies to go for in order to achieve this:

I would like at a certain moment, or at a certain time, to make client browsers with the web page already open, a button appear [as in the image]

[image]

When I send a request, make a button appear, either adding it to the DOM or make it appear (with css).

SSEs are a good solution? Is there another way to send a change to all clients (without refreshing the page)?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Comment: yes they are. i dont know what backend language / tech you use but https://socket.io/ would be also a choice

Comment: Would socket.io be a better solution than a native one even if I don't need bi-directional communication ?

Comment: in my opinion yes. however i dont know witch backend language you use. socket.io harmonic with node.js.

Comment: I have no backend at the moment, it's all plain client based. SSE examples go for PHP and socket.io with Node, I'm familiar with both. socket.io looks more clean and modern :)

Comment: yea. you can emit events to server aswell what you cannot with SSE as far as i know.